# When to set the rootViewController or to addSubview to main window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I know that in  `AppDelegate.m`, you must set the root controller for the application. Otherwise you will see nothing in your App and receive a warning.

I found that some materials use:

```
[window addSubview:anyViewController.view];
```

or use:

```
window.rootViewController = anyViewController;
```

Both methods could make the App start correctly. I can't understand why the first method doesn't set the rootviewController for the user, but it still works well. Why is this? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rootViewController` was added with iOS4 and is the newer and recommended method.

Comment: Yes, with the first example more than one view (each with their own view controller) could be added as subviews of the window. Which of them would be the rootViewController?

Comment: @ade Which "first example" are you talking about? I can only see `anyViewController`

Comment: first example: "[window addSubview:anyViewController.view];" which could be followed by "[window addSubview:anyViewController2.view];" etc.

Comment: @ade That would not be a correct way to go in iOS development. Things are not done that way. There's only one view controller just below the window in the hierarchy, other view controllers are managed by it.

Comment: Exactly my point, I've seen people do this and worse. This is why your assertion to use "window.rootViewController = anyViewController;" is correct. It is possible (but wrong) to add more than one view controller view as subviews to a window and it will work (as in not crash and I've just done it to test it in simulator and on device), but it is wrong to do so.

Comment: @ada Oh you were making a point, not asking a question, ok, yeah, true :)